# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code

Tags: java, websocket, handshake

I am getting this error when project was deployed in my clients server.

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://webserver:8080/Project/notificationendpoint' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

There is no problem running the code in my system. 
We both use Ubuntu 14.04.(32 bit). 
My chrome version: 47.0.2526.106. 
Client version: 48.0.2564.109

This is how i get the host location in js:

```
var wsUri = "ws://" + document.location.host + "/Project/notificationendpoint";
var websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

It connects to Server Endpoint:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/notificationendpoint",
    encoders = {NotifyEncoder.class},
    decoders = {NotifyDecoder.class})
public class Notification {
......
}
```

Comment: Well 404 is Not found ... double-check your endpoint and also make sure it is accessible from outside. I am always using `window.location.host` but I guess using `document` should be fine in your case...